# Read-only interface property that's read/writeable inside the implementation

Tags: c#, interface

I'd like to have an

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Foo { get; }
}
```

with an implementation like:

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    string IFoo.Foo { get; private set; }
}
```

I'd like the property to be gettable through the interface, but only writable inside the concrete implementation. What's the cleanest way to do this? Do I need to "manually" implement the getter and setter?

Comment: `protected` is the way to go.

Comment: Could you clarify? `string PartitionKey { get; protected set; }` yields an error "accessibility modifiers may not be used on accessors in an interface"

Comment: You'd need to implement the property with backing field - then you'd be able to access that field from concrete implementations (when set to protected). I don't think you can achieve that with auto properties.

Comment: What is the problem to use just set in the concrete class? then you can read and write it.

Comment: use `protected` on the `class` not the `interface`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Foo { get; }
}


abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string Foo { get; protected set; }
}
```

almost as you had it but `protected` and drop the `IFoo.` from the property in the class.

I suggest `protected` assuming you only want it accessable from INSIDE the derived class. If, instead, you'd want it fully public (able to be set outside the class too) just use:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, thanks! I thought the property inside `Bar` had to be `IFoo.Foo`, which was giving me errors.

Comment: but it gives errors "accessors must be more restrictive..."

Comment: @Stewart_R DotNetFiddle [works even better](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U0GGIK) for showing working code examples.

Comment: @Ahmad if it where explicit and protected `IFoo.Foo {get; protected set; }` the compiler will give two errors, but since one is complaining that you shouldn't even have a setter, the accessor issue is kinda moot.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That is THE most useful thing I have learned today! Love it! :-)

Comment: @Stewart_R Want to learn the 2nd most useful thing? In your answers put something similar to `[<kbd>Run Code</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U0GGIK)` below your code examples. It makes a "button" on the page people can click to run your example.

Comment: @Stewart_R right, sorry I didn't noticed you have public before the property.

Answer (score 2):

Why the explicit implementation of the interface? This compiles and works without problems:

```
interface IFoo { string Foo { get; } }
abstract class Bar : IFoo { public string Foo { get; protected set; } }
```

Otherwise, you could have a protected/private property for the class, and implement the interface explicitly, but delegate the getter to the class's getter.

Answer (score 2):

Either make the implementation implicit instead of explicit

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string Foo { get; protected set; }
}
```

Or add a backing field

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    protected string _foo;
    string IFoo.Foo { get { return _foo; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `protected set` and also remove the `IFO` before the property to make it implicit.

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Foo { get; }
}
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string Foo { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Because this is an explicit implementation you cannot add the setter.

Comment: @juharr Huh? Guys, that is just not true! The above code does not produce any errors: http://i.imgur.com/sLcXpeh.png

Comment: @Stewart_R that's because you don't have the explicit implementation `IFoo.Foo`.  Ahmad changed his answer since I made that comment, which is still true.

Comment: @juharr The question is a bit ambiguous, I think the OP means a protected property as other noticed, but it also could mean a read/writable property for the concrete implementation (instead inside the implementation)